# No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: druid

Seemingly out of the blue I'm getting this response to formerly working Druid queries. My guess is this isn't specific to Druid, but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
{
  "error" : "No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: [B@2862fe6e; line: 1, column: 1]"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that query send to druid is empty.

Easiest way to make this error is by executing query in wrong directory.

Directory structure:

```
/druid
    /config
    /examples
        /wikipedia
```

1. You have created query in directory /druid/examples/wikipedia
2. You have executed query in directory /druid/examples/wikipedia (it works)
3. You have went to /druid/config to change some configuration
4. You have executed old command using history feature of your shell (it doesn't work)